# UICollectionView first reusable table cell not showing up

Tags: swift

I am working on a game right now and my level selection isn't working right.

The first cell in the collection view won't show up and I can't figure out why.

Here is what it looks like:
[Picture of collection view with missing cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThjTY.png)

And here is my code for the UICollectionViewController:

the reuse IdentifierList is a list of strings that corresponds to the cells in the storyboard version of this. and I have already checked that they are all spelled correctly.

The one missing is the "MyCell" cell.

```
class UICollectionCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
   var reuseIdentifierList = ["MyCell",
                       "MyCell2",
                       "MyCell3",
                       "MyCell4",
                       "MyCell5",
                       "MyCell6",
                       "MyCell7",
                       "MyCell8",
                       "MyCell9",
                       "MyCell10",
                       "MyCell11",
                       "MyCell12",
                       "MyCell13",
                       "MyCell14",
                       "MyCell15",
                       "MyCell16",
                       "MyCell17",
                       "MyCell18"
                       ]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifierList[0]

    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return reuseIdentifierList.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierList[indexPath.item], for: indexPath)
    if indexPath.item != indexPath.startIndex {
     cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierList[indexPath.item], for: indexPath)

    }else{
       cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierList[0], for: indexPath)
    }

    print(indexPath.item)

    print(reuseIdentifierList[indexPath.item])
    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}


@IBAction func unwindToViewControllerLevel (sender: UIStoryboardSegue){

}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question: What do you have that many reuse identifier? Your cells look the same to me.

Comment: I have those because I couldn't figure out how to get the button numbers to change in them without having 18 different reusable views if there is a way to do this I would love to know.

Comment: so you want each cell to have a button with a different title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in creating that many cells. Just have an array to serve as your data source. In your case, it looks like you want your cells to have a button with numbers in order.

```
class UICollectionCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    // let dataSourceArray = [Int](1...20)  // [1, 2, 3 ..., 20]

    // EDIT -- SegueId
    let dataSourceArray = [(name: "1", segueId: "segueId1"), (name: "2", segueId: "segueId2"), (name: "3", segueId: "segueId3")]

    let cellId = "customCellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }    

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return dataSourceArray.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    let item = dataSourceArray[indexPath.item]
    cell.button.setTitle(item.name, for: .normal)
    let segueId = item.segueId
    // use segue id to perform different segues
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Would I still be able to add unique segues for each button and if so how would I do this?

Comment: You can have each button value correspond to a segue id which allows you to have different segues. See my update